# How to run (interpret) a Scheme program stored in a file?

Tags: scheme, read-eval-print-loop, chez-scheme

At the moment I am using the REPL-feature of Petite-Chez Scheme. This is working fine for small examples etc.

However, how can I store an entire program in a file ".scm", and then run (interpret) it from the command-line ? I am familiar with the (load "C:/..") command, however this only load definitions from a file into REPL.

How do I run programs using Scheme like programs in C/C++ where I compile and then execute the binary ".exe" ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Briefly, you just write your program in a file, put `#!/usr/bin/scheme --script` as the first line of the program, mark it executable, and run it. Here's a sample script that emulates the Unix `echo` command:

```
#!/usr/bin/scheme --script
(let ([args (cdr (command-line))])
  (unless (null? args)
    (let-values ([(newline? args)
                  (if (equal? (car args) "-n")
                      (values #f (cdr args))
                      (values #t args))])
      (do ([args args (cdr args)] [sep "" " "])
          ((null? args))
        (printf "~a~a" sep (car args)))
      (when newline? (newline)))))
```

See section 2.6 of [*Using Chez Scheme*](http://www.scheme.com/csug7/use.html#./use:h6) for details.

Comment: It seems as though the asker is using Windows. Still voted up because it's useful, however :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want an actual executable there are several implementations that supports compilation to native executable. [Racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/exe.html) is one of them and it supports many different scheme versions and dialects (R5RS, R6RS, Racket, ...). There are many more. [Chicken (R5RS + SRFIs)](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Getting%20started), [Gambit (R5RS + SRFIs)](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~gambit/doc/gambit-c.html#GSC) and [Bigloo (R5RS, + SRFIs)](http://www-sop.inria.fr/indes/fp/Bigloo/doc/bigloo-33.html#The-compiler-environment-and-options) to name a few.